# Update values in array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to come up with a way to update the values in an array of objects in mongo.  I have a collection which looks like

```
   [
     { CourseName: '',
       Sessions: [
              {
                 _id: null, //oops I didn't set this in the import
                 Name: 'blah',
                 Location: 'moon'
              }]
     }
    ]
```

Now I need to set the _id field.  I tried the documented approach of doing

```
db.Course.update({'Sessions._id': null}, {$set:{'Sessions.$._id': ObjectId()}}, false, true)
```

But I ran into this bug http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1055 which meant that I couldn't do it.  Is there some syntax which will allow me just to itterate over the collection and update each record by hand?  I tried a few things like

```
db.Course.find().forEach(
    function(course) 
    {
        course.Sessions.forEach(function(session)
            {
                session._id=ObjectId();
                course.Save(session); //Don't know how to save a single object
            });
    });
```

but they didn't work.  I'm looking for some way to just update that value in each session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
db.Course.find().forEach(
    function(course) 
    {
        course.Sessions.forEach(function(session)
            {
                session._id=ObjectId();
            });
        db.Course.save(course);
    });
```

However, you can run into problems saving stuff into a collection you're in the middle of iterating over, so I'd suggest loading a bunch of documents into an array, processing them, loading another batch, etc.